# Determine whether the user was authenticated in "LogoutView"

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

Django always show the **same** page when you go to `127.0.0.1:8000/admin/logout`, whether you were logged-in before or not.

What I want is showing a **Logout Successful Message** only ***if the user was authenticated before***; and show an error message if the user wasn't authenticated and try logging out.

I also need to include the **user's first_name** in my logout successful message.

I am using class-based `django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView` view like this:

```py
class SignoutView(LogoutView):
    template_name = "users/signout.html"

    def get_next_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get("next", "/")
        return redirect_to
```

and here is the template:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Sign out Page</h1>
<br>
{% if was_authenticated %}
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">You have logged out from your account {{first_name|capfirst}}!</h4>
  <p>Thanks for spending some quality time with my web site today.</p>
  <hr>
  <p class="mb-0" id="displayTimer"></p>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <h4 class="alert-heading">Ooh no!</h4>
  <p>Looks like you are not logged in! So you can not log out! Cool yeah?</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}


{% block js %}
{% if was_authenticated %}
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 5;
var url = "{{redirect_address}}";
var countdown = setInterval(function() {
  $('#displayTimer').text("You will be redirected to the home page in " + count-- + " seconds...");
  if (count < 0) {
    $('#displayTimer').text("Redirecting....");
    clearInterval(countdown);
    $(location).attr("href", url);
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I adding extra content to the view like this:

```py
class SignoutView(LogoutView):
    template_name = "users/signout.html"

    def set_extra_context(self):
        return {
            'was_authenticated': self.request.user.is_authenticated,
            'first_name': self.request.user.first_name,
        }

    def get_next_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get("next", "/")
        return redirect_to
```

but it seems like the function will run after the *logout process*, so `was_authenticated` will always be *False* and `first_name` always *None*.

I know how to handle this situation with *function-based views*, but I rather prefer using class-based views (if possible here!).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging the user out is the very first action in the `dispatch` method. So to capture data from that user, like first name, you'd have to override this method and capture that data before calling logout.

You could do something like;

```
@method_decorator(never_cache)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        self.first_name = request.user.first_name
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The line in the source for reference; https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L116

Answer (score 0):

In python (>= 3.6) script: Override `dispatch` method like bellow and add success message

```
from django.contrib import messages

class SignoutView(LogoutView):
    template_name = "users/signout.html"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.success(request, f'{request.user.first_name} successfully logged out')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'{request.user.first_name} your error message')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In template:

```
{% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert temp-alert {% if message.tags %}alert-{% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}danger{% else %}{{ message.tags }}{% endif %}{% endif %}" role="alert">{{ message }}</div>
          {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```